# Json parse return empty in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I ma using PLSQL. I have json. But when i parse the json, it retun empty. Here is the sample PLSQL code:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_process 
    IS
       myjson   VARCHAR2 (32767):= '{"responseinfo":"<TRANSACTION><RESPONSE_CODE>100</RESPONSE_CODE><RESPONSE_MSG>Duplicate Request Found.</RESPONSE_MSG></TRANSACTION>"}';
        l_json_obj    JSON_OBJECT_T;
        requestinfo   VARCHAR2 (32767);
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
        
            l_json_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse (myjson);
            requestinfo := l_json_obj.get_string ('requestinfo');
        END;


    END;
```

When I want get **requestinfo** from json, it return empty. What is the wrong of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has the key `responseinfo` and you are trying to get the value for `requestinfo`; you are not going to get the value because the two are different.

If you want `responseinfo` (and not `requestinfo`) then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_process 
IS
  myjson   VARCHAR2 (32767):= '{"responseinfo":"<TRANSACTION><RESPONSE_CODE>100</RESPONSE_CODE><RESPONSE_MSG>Duplicate Request Found.</RESPONSE_MSG></TRANSACTION>"}';
  l_json_obj    JSON_OBJECT_T;
  requestinfo   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
  l_json_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse (myjson);
  requestinfo := l_json_obj.get_string ('responseinfo');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(requestinfo);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> <TRANSACTION><RESPONSE_CODE>100</RESPONSE_CODE><RESPONSE_MSG>Duplicate Request Found.</RESPONSE_MSG></TRANSACTION>
> ```

If you do actually want `requestinfo` then that does not exist so a `NULL` response is valid.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-d6rTJNn)

Comment: @MTO Thanks for relpy. I am trying to get data in wrong key..